What makes something an organism?
Someone asked me this, and I didn't know how to respond. I think I know an adult human is an organism, or an embryo in-utero, but it doesn't seem right to say my somatic cells are also human organisms.
I saw self-sufficiency as an answer once, as somatic cells cannot obtain nutrients on their own, they are naturally part of and rely on a larger biological system, but this would exclude foetuses (and maybe parasites), as they rely on the mother.
What makes something an organism? This is an answer from another posting on here:

An organism is any system of components which depend on each other for survival and cooperate in proliferating potentially unboundedly.

However the person who proposed this admitted that this does not apply to organisms who are sterile.
